# how to setup civicrm on windows 8

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civicrm-home, civicrm-buildkit

Please could anybody direct me on how to setup civiCRM on my windows OS and also code with it. I am totally new to this type of platform and with no clue on how to go about anything, however, I have a strong knowledge of PHP and php based frameworks like laravel and lumen. I believe if directed on what to do I should be able to standard on my own. I have tried google but nothing significant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a Windows web development environment like [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and need to create a site on localhost. There you could install wordpress/Drupal/Joomla any of those for which civicrm is available to be installed and then follow steps to install civicrm following docs here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Hassan, however, I already have a XAMPP server, I believe this would suffice. The next step would be to install drupal of which I dont know how. I am totally new to CMS although I have being coding PHP for sometime. If I succeed in installing  drupal then what next. I need some kind of guide. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Drupal instructions for that inatall.